# RecurrenceTable and While

Tags: iteration

Good day.

Let's take an example from Help on `RecurrenceTable`:

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 0.7 x[n] + y[n], y[n + 1] == -0.7989995 + x[n]^2, x[0] == 0.142857, 
y[0] == 0.33}, {x, y}, {n, 1, 2500}]
```

How to add here a `While` condition so that iterations stop after `x[n]` reached some threshold value, smth like `While[x[n] > -1, <continue recurrence>)]`?

**ADD**

I need this because in my real code for some initial conditions there will be overflow, so MMA issues warnings, and I think it is better to stop iterations at some threshold.

**ADD 2**

Simple approach, but I think not efficient in terms of time and memory, would be this:

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == If[x[n] < -1, -10, 0.7 x[n] + y[n]], 
y[n + 1] == If[x[n] < -1, -10., -0.7989995 + x[n]^2], 
x[0] == 0.142857, y[0] == 0.33}, {x, y}, {n, 0, 10}] /.{-10., -10.}->Nothing
```

Of course, here we have unneeded iterations.

Comment: Like a [`WhenEvent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) for recurrence tables? Great idea!

Comment: @Roman, there are `NestWhile`, `FoldWhile`, but I need smth like `RecurrenceTableWhile`, not sure this is possible.

Comment: Did you try `WhenEvent`?

Comment: @Rom38, no I have no idea how to add it here.

Answer (score 3):

For an explicit recurrence relation like yours, an iterative approach with [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) works:

```
NestWhileList[{0.7 #[[1]] + #[[2]], -0.7989995 + #[[1]]^2} &,
              {0.142857, 0.33},
              #[[1]] > -1 &]

(*    {{0.142857, 0.33},
       {0.43, -0.778591},
       {-0.477591, -0.6141},
       {-0.948414, -0.570906},
       {-1.2348, 0.100489}}       *)
```

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of `NestWhile`, but if I need to use simple `RecurrenceTable`, is it possible to add `While` in it?